# Open external application with electron

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, electron

I want to create a personal app with Electron to manage other apps on my device. The problem is that I try in different ways to create a link that opens my own .exe applications but this is not allowed. Is there a way to do it or is it impossible?
I leave my link code below.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1>"Aplication"</h1>
        <button>
            <a href="options/hollow.bat">Hollow</a>
        </button>
    </div>
```

This link refers to a .bat file.

```
START D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/HollowKnight/hollow_knight.exe
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a batch file to open another program?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this as [@LeonardoPF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2277678/leonardopf) mentioned...

So you have your HTML file as so and link your `app.js` function (in this case we will call it `doSomething()`

```html
<!-- FILE: index.html --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1>Application</h1>
        <button>
            <a onclick="doSomething()">Hollow</a>
        </button>
    </div>
```

One way you can do this is using [shell](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell) as follows...

Now, in our script file that we hooked called `app.js`, we write that function.
For this, we will just directly link it to the executable you just linked above.

#### Method #1

```js
// FILE: app.js
const { shell } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const app = path.join("D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/HollowKnight/hollow_knight.exe");
// Open a local file in the default app


function doSomething(){
   shell.openExternal(app);
}
```

I haven't tested this one but apparently you can also use `.openItem()`.

#### Method #2

```js
// FILE: app.js
const { shell } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const app = path.join("D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/HollowKnight/hollow_knight.exe");


// Open a local file in the default app
function doSomething(){
   shell.openItem(app);
}
```

Another way is using the `child_process` library...

#### Method #1

```js
// FILE: app.js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const path = require('path');
const app = path.join("D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/HollowKnight/hollow_knight.exe");


// spawn the application process
function doSomething(){
   spawn(app);
}
```

#### Method #2

```js
// FILE: app.js
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const path = require('path');
const app = path.join("D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/HollowKnight/hollow_knight.exe");


// Execute the file
function doSomething(){
   execFile(app, function(err, stdout) {
       if(err){
          console.error(err);
          return;
       }
       console.log(stdout);
   });
}
```

Comment: 2024, now only openPath & openExternal, no openItem any more: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell#shellopenpathpath

Answer (score 0):

There is different ways to do that, but the simplest way to open a file with the default OS application is to use the [shell](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell):

```
const { shell } = require('electron')
shell.openExternal('options/hollow.bat')
```